# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, google-api

**Resumen**

Intento implementar el *recaptcha* de google en mi formulario pero me sale un error de *javascript*. El error es así en consola

```
index.php:288 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $ is not defined at index.php:288:7
```

**Problema**

Segun el video que ví y me estoy guiando para implementar *recaptcha* el código está bien, igual al mio ...

Aquí llamo la API de Google incluyendo las contraseñas

```
<!--ReCapcha-->
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=<?php echo SITE_KEY;?>"></script>
    <!---->
```

**HTML**

```
<from action="" method="post" id="loginForm"> 

        <input type="text" name="entrar" id="entrar">

        <button type="button"   class="formulario__btn">Enviar</button>

    </from>
```

**PHP con salida en javascript**

```
<script type="text/Javascript"> 
                grecaptcha.ready(function(){

                    grecaptcha.execute('<?php echo SITE_KEY;?>', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {

                        console.log(token);

                        $('#entrar').val(token);
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: ¿Tienes agregado JQuery en la ubicación correcta dentro de tu documento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta era ... muy simple, solo debia de implementar la libreria de Jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

la solución era muy simple, tengo que darle el token al JS de diferente manera, asi:

```
<script type="text/Javascript"> 
               grecaptcha.ready(function(){

                   grecaptcha.execute('<?php echo SITE_KEY;?>', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
                       document.getElementById("entrar").value = token;
                   });
               });
           </script>
```

Comment: Es decir, estabas intentando usar sintaxis que requiere JQuery y, al usar Javascript común y corriente, funcionó :)